# react component using hooks sync state count down time with local storage

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, local-storage, event-listener

```js
import React , {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const Timer = () =>{
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState(120);
    
    const countTimer = () =>{
        if(timer <= 0){
             localStorage.clear("timer");
             console.log("timer less then 0")
             return;
        } else {
            console.log("greater then 0")
            setTimer(timer -1) ;
            localStorage.setItem("timer",timer);
            setTimeout(countTimer(),1000);
        }
    }
    
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(localStorage.getItem("timer")){
            setTimer(localStorage.getItem("timer"));
        } else {
            setTimer(120);
        }
        if(timer){
            setTimeout(countTimer(),1000);
        }
    },[timer])
    return (
        <div align="center">
            Timer :{timer}  
        </div>
    )
}

export default Timer
```

My Goal is to implement count down timer in react which will be sync with localstorage and across browser tabs with page showing the counter,
want to sync timer of state and local storage timer, putting them in useEffect of timer change updating timer of state and updating local storage inside setTimeout , Please! help me , thank you

Comment: Please provide more context to the problem you are facing and also format the code properly for others to answer the question in a much better way!

Comment: implementing count down timer in react which will be sync with localstorage and across browser tabs with page showing the counter please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code.

The first problem is `setTimeout` accepts a callback function as it's first agrument. That it will execute after the time provided as the second argument. But instead of passing function `countTimer` as a callback you're passing the result of it's execution.

```js
if(timer){
    setTimeout(countTimer(),1000); // here you're passing as the callback 
                                   // the result of execution of countTimer
                                   // namely `undefined` value
}
```

Another problem is you're calling `setTimeout` twice. Inside `useEffect` hook that will be executed each time the `timer` variable changes and inside `countTimer` function on each execution.

One more problem. Each time when `timer` variable changes you're reading `timer` key from `localStorage` and setting `setTimer` again. When `state` gets changed withing `useEffect` it will cause React to [schedule another render](https://github.com/Eliav2/how-react-hooks-work#super-important-notes). And your code will trigger almost endless loop. That will rerender the component constantly untill the time runs out.

And yet another problem. If your component gets unmounted while the timeout still runs. The pending functions eventually will get executed. It will write to localStorage the `timer` value it had before unmounting. And if you mount this component again that pending timeout when executed may overwrite the newly created value.

That's a good habit to clear any pending timeouts or other effects on unmounting. So you're better off cleaning setTimeout if it still runs. For that you'll have to return [`cleanup`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) function as a return value from `useEffect` hook.

As a summary:

- Pass the callback function into `setTimeout`, not a result of it's execution
- Do not create multiple pending timeouts
- Do not trigger endless rerenders inside `useEffect`
- Cleanup pending timeouts on component unmount

So all in all it should look like that:

```js
import * as React from 'react'

const Timer = () => {
    const initialTimer = localStorage.getItem("timer") ?? 120;
    const timeoutId = React.useRef(null);
    const [timer, setTimer] = React.useState(initialTimer);

    const countTimer = React.useCallback(() => {
        if (timer <= 0) {
            localStorage.clear("timer");
        } else {
            setTimer(timer - 1);
            localStorage.setItem("timer", timer);
        }
    }, [timer]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        timeoutId.current = window.setTimeout(countTimer, 1000);
        // cleanup function
        return () => window.clearTimeout(timeoutId.current);
    }, [timer, countTimer]);

    return <div align="center">Timer :{timer}</div>;
}

export default Timer
```

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-jones-y5nk0?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you so much but across tabs the timer is not in sync, can you please help with that

Comment: When opening a couple tabs at codesandbox it looks perfectly fine for me. Can you elaborate the exact problem? It may unsync for the period inside timeout. But that's rather complex problem. You'l have to assign `leader`-`follower` relations between tabs to make only leader write into the localStorage and when leader get's closed make reelection and assign another tab as a leader. That's far beyond simple stackoverflow answer.

Comment: i want to have two timer one is idle timer and another is pop up timer, if there is no activity on page idle timer(for 10 sec) should trigger timer pop up timer for 20 sec