# Create a count up timer in React JS that resumes on page change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, timer

I have a timer function that counts up along with start, pause, and reset functionalities. Now, I have to make it so that when the page is changed within the application or refreshed, the timer is paused and resumed when I return to the timer page. I've read about using sessionStorage, localStorage, and useContext, but am not able to figure out how to use these in my program. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react component using hooks sync state count down time with local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68134405/react-component-using-hooks-sync-state-count-down-time-with-local-storage)

Answer (score 0):

As you said, I would recommend using localStorage. Session storage only persists until the user closes the tab, but localStorage will persist until removed. You can use localStorage as follows:

```js
//Set item:
localStorage.setItem("foo", "bar") //The first item is the key, the second is the value you are storing

//Get item:
localStorage.getItem("foo") //Will return "bar"
```

I would recommend storing the timestamp for the end-time of the timer in localStorage when the timer is first started. Then, you can remove this value when the timer reaches 0. This will allow you to also then read the value from localStorage when the page is first loaded to see if it has a value, and if it does you can know when the timer will end.